# Learning useful semantic representations of data

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, feature-engineering, computer-vision, triplet-loss

Training a neural network on its final task (e.g. classification) right from the beginning is not always the best way to go. I'd like to make a short list of recognized methods of motivating a NN to learn useful representations of data. This is in my opinion closely related to preventing shortcuts in learning ("person A is the one with ear piercing").

- Siamese and [Triplet Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6622)
- Autoencoders
- self-supervised learning with interesting synthetic target and loss

  - matching high-res small patches of pictures with low-res whole pictures
  - solving jigsaw puzzles (everything from [keras blog](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) so far)
- [Confusing Domains](http://ruder.io/transfer-learning/index.html#confusingdomains)

What else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Language modelling is the most widely used pre-training/self-supervised task. Word embeddings are naturally transferred to be used in some downstream task.

For vision, rotations and denoising is popular. There is also in-painting, though it doesn't work as well at the moment.

For reinforcement learning, there is [structure-from-motion](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.07780), and self-play.

For vision-and-language tasks, there are now many joint-modality networks whose secret sauce is in the pre-training tasks that they do. For instance, LXMERT and VisualBERT

Recently there has been an incredible proliferation of self-supervision tasks; 
this is an active and exciting area of research!